# So nearly so as to

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms, idiom-requests, idiom-meaning

While reading the book Introduction to Mathematical Logic by Alonso Church, I have met with the idiom '**so nearly so as to**' of which meaning I hardly grasp from context:

> Again the sentence "Sir Walter Scott is the author of Waverley" must have the same denotation as the sentence "Sir Walter Scott is the man who wrote twenty-nine Waverley Novels altogether," since the name "the author of Waverley" is replaced by another name of the same person; the latter sentence, it is plausible to suppose, if it is not synonymous with "The number, such that Sir Walter Scott is the man who wrote that many Waverley Novels altogether, is twenty-nine," is at least **so nearly so as to** ensure its having the same denotation; and from this last sentence in turn, replacing the complete subject by another name of the same number, we obtain, as still having the same denotation, the sentence "The number of counties in Utah is twenty-nine".

Another appearance of 'so nearly so as so to' [but with a coma insterted] I have found after a quick googling is in a letter written by Major General Arthur St. Clair to George Washington dated on 27 July 1779:

> As your Excellency has desired my Opinion with Respect to such offensive Operations as may be undertaken against the Ennemy, taking into Consideration the Strength of both Armies, and the State of our military Stores, I am very free to give it that our Position admits of no considerable Change, untill the Works here are finished, or **so nearly so, as to** leave the Completion of them in the Power of their proper Garrison, within the Time that will probably elapse before they are attempted by the Ennemy.

Any help in understanding the meaning of this idiom is well appreciated!

Comment: "so nearly so as to..." in the first example means "so nearly synonymous as to...". It's sense 1a of [so adverb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so)

Comment: Wonder the cause of the negative vote...